# regex function 4 letters and 4 numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i dont understand how regex works so this may be is a simple question for many people, but for me is very important that a person can explain me with simple words how can i use this.

i need to validate in jquery adding a new function

```
$.validator.addMethod("loginRegex",function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^[a-zA-Z\d]+$/.test(a)},"Solo se aceptan letras o numeros");
```

this function accept only letters and numbers, but if you put FH374HD3 the validate return me true, but i need to valid 4 letters and 4 numbers in that order, example: "ABCD4578", only letters and numbers but 4 letters first and 4 numbers at the end.

is that posible??? tnx all!

Comment: adding one question, what's mean of "+$" at the end of regex expression... no important question but i want to learn

Comment: You don't understand regex? What a perfect time to start learning! Read some docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Writing_a_Regular_Expression_Pattern. Also useful: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @MattBall i dont speak english, so when i learn speak better i read the guides, at that time... i have to use stackoverflow! thanx stackoverflow and tnx all because my english sucks but you answer all the time!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will match a string that is exactly 8 characters long that starts with exactly four letters and is followed by four numbers:

```
/^[a-z]{4}\d{4}$/i
```

This could also be written as:

```
/^[A-Za-z]{4}\d{4}$/
```

with the case insensitivity placed inline.

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `[a-z]` matches the letters from lower case `a` to lower case `z`
- `{4}` matches the previous selection 4 times (`[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]` but in fewer characters)
- `\d` matches digits (equivalent to `[0-9]`)
- `{4}` is as above (`\d\d\d\d` but in fewer characters)
- `$` matches the end of the string
- `i` is the case-insensitivity flag so that `[a-z]` matches for capital letters as well.

It should also be noted that this will not match for special characters such as é or à as they are not in the range `[a-z]`.

Comment: wich is the difference between /i and /

Comment: @andrescabana86 [**read the docs.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags)

Comment: `[A-z]` is not equivalent to a case-insensitive `[a-z]`. There are characters between `Z` and `a` that are not "letters". `[A-Za-z]` would the the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z]{4}\d{4}$/ is right?? 4 letters 4 numbers and only 8 digits uppercase lowercase letters

Comment: @eldarerathis, thanks for that, silly mistake on my part. [regexes are hard](http://xkcd.com/1171/).

Answer (score 2):

You can validate 4 capitals and 4 numbers using the following:

```
^[A-Z]{4}\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 2):

as already posted try this : 
    ^[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}

matches exactly 4 letters (capitals aswell) and 4 numbers

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want a regex that will only validate 4 letters and then 4 numbers in sequence?

Maybe something like:

```
/^[A-Za-z]{4}\d{4}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate the expression.

```
^[a-zA-Z]{4}[\d]{4}$
```

You can test it in sites like [this one](http://regexpal.com/) so you can play out with regular expressions (and spend some time)...

Comment: thanx for the web, i think is the best help that anybody can give me to this question and future questions

Answer (score 0):

The following regex can be used

To consider the order of characters:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{4}[\d]{4}$
```

Ex:

```
6754uYhG -> Failure 

uYhG6754 -> Success
```

To not consider the order of characters.

```
^[a-zA-Z]{4}[\d]{4}|[\d]{4}[a-zA-Z]{4}$
```

Ex:

```
6754uYhG -> Success 

uYhG6754 -> Success
```